# My javascript is not working (w jquery as well)

Tags: javascript

I am not able to get my javascript to work
html:

```
<div id="tomato">
    <body>
        <button id="totato">total</button>
    </body>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("totato").click = potato();

  function potato() {
    $("tomato").css("background", "red");
  }
})
```

Comment: You are missing `#`=> `id` selector

Comment: Along with using the wrong selector, you are also not setting click correctly, look at the [jquery click docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Ok it is working with the # added, but I see that it is not running correctlyhttp://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxGzRe

Answer (score 1):

> You are missing `#`=> `id` selector

Event binding should be implement using `.on()` which will expect first argument as `event` and second argument will be `function expression(callback function)`

Note that you have parenthesis`()` around your function name which will invoke function when that line is executed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#totato").on('click', potato);

  function potato() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tomato">

  <body>
    <button id="totato">total</button>
  </body>
</div>
```

**OR**

Use `.click()` which will expect argument as `function expression(callback function)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#totato").click(potato);

  function potato() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tomato">

  <body>
    <button id="totato">total</button>
  </body>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div#tomato must be IN the body tag. Not external body but internal body

Answer (score 0):

Put a `#` in front of your selectors in the javascript.